# heroku gunicorn / Flask app error "Exception in worker process"

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn

We deploy our app to heroku (`git heroku push`);
It uses `gunicorn` and other requirements (see below for requirements.txt)

The output of `heroku logs --tail` include this message, including *"Exception in worker process..."*

We tried different versions of Python, we tried different versions of our libraries , and we tried renaming our app.py file / app variable -- but still the error, which does not mention our code in the stack trace...

```
2019-10-23T23:47:16.828218+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-23 23:47:16 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:58467 (4)
2019-10-23T23:47:16.82839+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-23 23:47:16 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-10-23T23:47:16.834106+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-23 23:47:16 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842032+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-23 23:47:16 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842035+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842038+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-10-23T23:47:16.84204+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842042+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842044+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842046+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842048+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-10-23T23:47:16.84205+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842052+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842054+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842056+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842057+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-10-23T23:47:16.842059+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
```

Our heroku config files include:
Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app: app
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.6.9
```

requirements.txt:

```
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
dnspython==1.16.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.17.2
pandas==0.25.1
pymongo==3.9.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
ujson==1.35
urllib3==1.25.6
Werkzeug==0.16.0
wincertstore==0.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My procfile was wrong, there should **not** be a space between `app: app`. The [`gunicorn` documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html) basic usage:

> `$ gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE`
>
> Where APP_MODULE is of the pattern `$(MODULE_NAME):$(VARIABLE_NAME)`.

*Wrong*:

```
web: gunicorn app: app
```

*Right*:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

I was confusing the [heroku Procfile syntax](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) with the `gunicorn` command;

- The [heroku Procfile syntax](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) **does** allow a space after specifying the `web` in the `"process type": "command"` combination; e.g. `web: gunicorn` ...
- Whereas the `gunicorn` command does **not** allow a space; e.g. `app:app`